# Is there a way to upload flutter's obfuscation mappings to Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: flutter, firebase, obfuscation, crashlytics, stack-trace

My flutter app uses obfuscation for builds and creates symbols.
The crash stacktraces are appearing obfuscated in the Firebase Crashlytics console.
I know that we can use "flutter symbolize -i command" to deobfuscate a stacktrace, but is there a way to upload this symbols to Firebase Crashlytics console?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=flutter#add-sdk), if your Flutter project uses the --split-debug-info flag (and, optionally, the --obfuscate flag), you need to use the Firebase CLI (v.11.9.0+) to upload Android symbols.

From the root directory of your Flutter project, run the following command:

```
firebase crashlytics:symbols:upload --app=APP_ID PATH/TO/symbols
```

The PATH/TO/symbols directory is the same directory that you pass to the --split-debug-info flag when building the application.

Also, you can find the app ID in the firebase_options.dart file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked, is there a way to upload it for iOS too?

Comment: It looks like it's not yet supported, I found this Github issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5291